# C# SMS Sending Error ( AT Commands)

Tags: c#, command

Hey guys I am trying to send SMS from window Forms using AT commands . But getting stuck at this function . It says "`Failed to set message format.`"

```
recievedData = ExecCommand(port,"AT+CMGF=1", 1000, "Failed to set message format."); // Error in this line => Failed to set message format

String command = "AT+CMGS=\"" + PhoneNo + "\"";
                recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");         
                command = Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";
                recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 3000, "Failed to send message"); //3 seconds
                if (recievedData.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
                {
                    isSend = true;
                }
                else if (recievedData.Contains("ERROR"))
                {
                    isSend = false;
                }
                return isSend;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex; 
            }

        }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com  Read this it might be helpful to you ...

Comment: @AnantDabhi thank you for considering my post..But as a matter of fact i have taken this code from the site you mentioned, and the error is coming from that same code.
My mobile is connected to the right port, but just could not getting pass that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to send a message using HyperTerminal..
then this is the code i have

```
_serialPort.Open();
_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
_serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + mobilenumber + "\"\r\n");
_serialPort.Write("My Mesage" + "\x1A");
_serialPort.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you Rashid... I'll check that out, But will that code send SMS to my mobile number?

Comment: yes you can send SMS anyone through this code..when you configured your port correctly

Comment: Thanks Rashid... I'll check that n let u know . :)

Comment: No problem bro... :) try it.. i ve an sms server on C# too.. i can give if u require..

Comment: Rashid... Hey.
I'm afraid its not working either.. It says that message sent, but i m unable to receive msg on my mobile...

Comment: have you tried on hyper terminal?? is ur gsm modem sending msgs through hyper terminal?

Comment: I am Afraid i m using Visual studio for that purpose... dont know how to use hyper Terminal?